# Can't delete system files from System32/drivers. Need permission

Tags: windows-7, permissions

How to delete specific files in **System32/drivers**?

I need to remove a software manually.Guide says that I need to remove some **.sys** files that are related to that software from **System32/drivers** but I can't. I get the **"You need permission to perform this action"**. The permission is required from **SYSTEM**. I'm logged in as **local administrator**. Tried using **Unlocker**, giving myself full access to the files and even to **Everyone**. Tried deleting through **safe mode**. One of the files I took ownership with **takeown** and **cacls** and now it's asking me I need permission from myself(**administrator account**)!

How to delete system files if I'm logged in as local admin and still need permission from SYSTEM?

Some of the files I need to delete: **srtspx64.sys** and **srtspl64.sys**

http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH91038&locale=en_US

Comment: Use a linux live system. Rename the files and reboot.

Comment: Please read http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit.

Summary: Removal is never guaranteed. Before ever using that PC again for anything sensitive (such as Internet banking) first nuke the OS from orbit. Do a clean reinstall.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it easily via:
Executing :

```
takeown /f srtspx64.sys
cacls srtspx64.sys /E /P /g abc:f
del srtspl64.sys /f /p
del srtspx64.sys /f /p
```

**Replace abc with your username**

Comment: Please do not post links to files in random download locations.

Comment: What are you even talking about.  This is the best answer on the site.

Comment: @ojblass The answer was edited a few years ago, probably had a download link at the time

Comment: This anonymous genious needs to report to Stockholm immediately for his/her Nobel Prize.

Answer (score 3):

Files in System32 are typically owned by "TrustedInstaller" and are locked down really tightly. If you really, absolutely feel you must do this, the easiest way is to boot from a Linux LiveCD or a Windows install disk.

Using Linux, mount the drive R/W with the `ntfs-3g` utility (or just use `mount`; all modern Linux distros default to using ntfs-3g) and delete the files like you would any others (from a shell, the command is `rm`). I know this approach works.

Using Windows install media, you need to enter repair / recovery mode. That will give you the option to open a command prompt. This prompt can be used to browse to the folder (note that it may not be on the `C:` drive, if the install media is putting itself as `C:`) and try deleting the file, potentially using the same kinds of things you did above (taking ownership, changing ACLs, etc.). This *should* work, but I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 2):

> Note
>   That deleting any thing under the windows folder can cause the
>   entire system to stop working!
>   Just because you are logged in as a local admin does
>   not mean that all processes you start run with full access you have to
>   start them in admin mode!

You could try to start CMD in administrator mode and then delete the files with the DEL command.

If you still can't delete the file you could use handle.exe found in [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/) to see if some other process is locking the file.

Comment: DEL says 'Access denied'. Sysinternals doesn't work, says "Error loading driver: A". Yes, just "A".

Comment: @user317441 Sorry i have no more ideas.. but if you ask me i would rather reinstall the computer then fiddle with the system32 folder.

Answer (score 1):

Use [IOBit Unlocker](http://www.iobit.com/en/iobit-unlocker.php), it's a great tool, super easy to use, free, and I can vouch that it deleted my rogue drivers from System32\drivers.
See other options [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/128680/how-to-delete-move-or-rename-locked-files-in-windows/) (but I only tried Unlocker).